# How long does the General Number Field Sieve actually take?

Tags: computational-complexity, prime-factorization, sieve-theory

According to the researchers who cracked it, [RSA-768](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-768) took an equivalent 2000 years to factor on a 2.2GHz single-core computer.

Using the [complexity equation](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32508) for the [General Number Field Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) with `n=2^768` yielded `8.7*10^31` operations (calculated using Maxima). Let's naively assume a computer can perform 1 billion operations per second. Then that comes out to `2.73*10^13` years. That's off the reported value of `2.0*10^3` years by 10 orders of magnitude!

What am I missing? Calculations I did for other primes yielded similar over-estimates. Am I doing something wrong? Or is the complexity bound really just that loose?

Comment: please, write your calculations from $8.7\cdot 10^{31}$ to $2.73\cdot 10^{13}$

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; do you just want me to write the intermediate steps? Both calculations are essentially just plug and chug but if you think that would help I'll add them.

Comment: Intermediate steps) and is "your" biliion $10^9$ or $10^{12}$?

Comment: @Mr.Newman I did in fact mean $10^9$; a modern single-core computer can't possibly perform $10^{12}$ operations per second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your "complexity equation". Replace the constant $\sqrt{\frac{64}{9}}$ by $\sqrt[3]{\frac{64}{9}}$. Wolfram Mathematica says, that if $N=2^{768}$, that
$$\exp{\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{64}{9}}(\ln N)^{1/3}(\ln \ln N)^{2/3}\right)}/10^{12}/3600/24/365=3.41\cdot 10^3$$

In view of [Coppersmith's paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00198464) this constant can be $\frac{1}{3}(92+26\sqrt{13})^{1/3}=1.902$, with respect to some modifications of the method, and, so, result time is $1.9\cdot 10^3$.

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure that's just a different approximation. In my brief searches there is actually some debate about what exactly that constant should be. I have seen the equation with both the squareroot which is 2.667 and (1 plus the cuberoot) which is 2.923. In either case such a small difference should note result in 10 orders of magnitude error.

Comment: @TheSchwa: $\sqrt[3]{\frac{64}{9}}$ is correct. And it is $\sqrt[3]{\frac{64}{9}} + o(1)$, not $\sqrt[3]{\frac{64}{9}} + 1$. So Mr.Newman's answer is spot on. (Think about it: how could $\sqrt\frac{64}{9}$ not be a misprint?!)

Comment: Ah woops good point >.<

Comment: Although I'm still surprised changing the constant by 0.3 resulted in a difference of 8 orders of magnitude between answers; exponential growth not intuitive and etc. Thanks for pointing out the error :)

Comment: I just realized there's still a problem here; a 2.2GHz single core computer couldn't possibly do $10^{12}$ operations per second...according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS#Computing) and it's [Dell reference](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/high-performance-computing/w/wiki/2329.aspx), we can estimate that the single-core 2.2GHz computer can perform $4*2.2*10^9 = 8.8$ GFLOPS, and so it's general performance must be somewhat less than that. Using $10^{12}$ gives millions of years instead of thousands. Thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "this constant can be". Which constant? Are you replacing $(64/9)^{1/3}$ with 1.902 ?

Answer (score 1):

@TheSchwa, did you ever resolve your final comment about $10^9$ vs $10^{12}$?

[In the paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/006.pdf) published by the researchers who cracked RSA-768 they say:

> Our computation required more than $10^{20}$ operations. With the equivalent of almost 2000 years of computing on a single core 2.2GHz AMD Opteron, on the order of $2^{67}$ instructions were carried out.

More precisely, it required $1.4757 \times 10^{20}$ operations (my calculation, just $2^{67}$). I'm speculating that to get their "almost 2000 years" they divided the number of operations ($1.4757 \times 10^{20}$) by the estimated FLOPs of the machine (sockets = 1, $\times$ cores = 1, $\times$ clock cycles = $2.2 \times 10^9$, $\times$ Ops/cycle = just over 1 (by implication)) which would give "almost" 2000 years of processing.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).